# how to close popup DIV by clicking anywhere on the body

Tags: javascript

I have an overlay DIV that appear once a user clicks on a link. The user can close the overlay by clicking on the "X" link within the DIV. I want the user to be able to close the overlay DIV by clicking anywhere on the page. Please help me to implement this functionality. Following are my code...

```js
$(function(){
  var mHeight = $(window).height();
  var popHeight = $(window).height();
  var mWidth = $(window).width();
  var popWidth = $(window).width();
  
  $(".pop_Show").click(function(){
    if(mHeight < popHeight){
      $(".pop_Content").css({position: "absolute", "margin-top": "0"});
      $(".pop_Content").animate({top: '0'}, "slow");
    }else{
      $(".pop_Content").animate({top: '50px'}, "slow");
    }
    if(mWidth < popWidth){
      $(".pop_Content").css({left: "0", "margin-left": "0"});
    }
    $("body").append("<div class='disable_bg'></div>");
  });
  

//Script for hiding the overlay div by clicking on X
  
  $(".pop_Close").click(function(){
    var popHeight2 = popHeight+500;
    $(".pop_Content").animate({top: "-"+popHeight2}, "100",function(){$(".disable_bg").remove();});
  });
  
  
// I want the script for hiding the overlay by clicking anywhere in the page
  
});
```

```css
.pop_Content {
  overflow: hidden; 
  z-index:2500; 
  position:fixed; 
  top:-2000px; 
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-150px;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background:#ccc;
  padding:15px;
}
.pop_Close{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1000;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  float:right; 
  cursor:pointer;
  margin:0px 10px;
  color:#595959;
  font:1.5em verdana;
  text-align:center;
}
.pop_Close:before {
  content: "x";
}
.disable_bg {
  background: black;
  opacity: .5;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 2450;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <a href="#" class="pop_Show">Click Me</a>

  <!--Overlay Div-->
  <div class="pop_Content"><a class="pop_Close"></a>
  I am the Overlay Div
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try $("body > *").not(".tc_bg").click(function(){....})

Comment: Kindly post your full code. Snippet is something that is mainly used for showing the full code.

Comment: I have added the full code below. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add an event listener that can check if you've clicked on the overlay background. I have modified the code so that it re-uses the same element instead of creating a new one each time. This adds the event listener each time you append the overlay's background (jQuery removes the event listeners on removal). I also modified the logic of the click event listener so that it only targets click events that directly match the element the listener was applied to. This prevents the overlay from being closed by clicking on the content inside of it.

```js
$(function(){
  var mHeight = $(window).height();
  var popHeight = $(window).height();
  var mWidth = $(window).width();
  var popWidth = $(window).width();
  var disable_bg =  $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('disable_bg'), closeFn;
  
  $(".pop_Show").click(function(){
    if(mHeight < popHeight){
      $(".pop_Content").css({position: "absolute", "margin-top": "0"});
      $(".pop_Content").animate({top: '0'}, "slow");
    }else{
      $(".pop_Content").animate({top: '50px'}, "slow");
    }
    if(mWidth < popWidth){
      $(".pop_Content").css({left: "0", "margin-left": "0"});
    }
   $('body').append(disable_bg);
   disable_bg.click(closeFn);
  });
  

//Script for hiding the overlay div by clicking on X
  
  $(".pop_Close").click(closeFn = function(e){
    if(e.target !== this) return;
    var popHeight2 = popHeight+500;
    $(".pop_Content").animate({top: "-"+popHeight2}, "100",function(){disable_bg.remove()});
  });
  
// I want the script for hiding the overlay by clicking anywhere in the page
  
});
```

```css
.pop_Content {
  overflow: hidden; 
  z-index:2500; 
  position:fixed; 
  top:-2000px; 
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-150px;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background:#ccc;
  padding:15px;
}
.pop_Close{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1000;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  float:right; 
  cursor:pointer;
  margin:0px 10px;
  color:#595959;
  font:1.5em verdana;
  text-align:center;
}
.pop_Close:before {
  content: "x";
}
.disable_bg {
  background: black;
  opacity: .5;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 2450;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <a href="#" class="pop_Show">Click Me</a>

  <!--Overlay Div-->
  <div class="pop_Content"><a class="pop_Close"></a>
  I am the Overlay Div
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.. this is what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't give a lot of information about your HTML-structure I have to imagine what it might look like.

What you can do is close the overlay by clicking on the overlay itself.

```
jQuery( ".tc_bg" ).click(function() {
    var popHeight2 = popHeight + 500;

    jQuery( ".menu_pop" ).animate({
        top: "-" + popHeight2
    }, "100", function() {
        jQuery( ".tc_bg" ).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: @Manu Have you tried the selector `'*:not(.tc_bg)'` ?